# Problem with texturing an alembic object

Tags: texturing

I created a small scene in Houdini and exported the objects as separate files.

Then I try to texture the object, it only creates the color, in the viewport and rendering

For the back plane(blender plane) I have created a texture and I am trying to create a same texture for the floor

What should I do?

Result
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12gH_Hfdlz4fkhL8OcFc7Aa51gtXVUAXW/view?usp=sharing

Shader Editor
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yeO2PiKr1Bd4eLwlGAZkQcJ5tF7NO1-N/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Duplicate back plane ... ? It is not clear to me what do you mean "it creates only the color". And it is not clear what you have tried and we're did you fail. In general - if you use UV coordinates, your object has to be unwrapped ... object needs to contains UVMap. BTW please insert images into your Q, external links are not allowed for their future permanents

Comment: Please use the editing tools here, you can add pictures directly into your question. It is not desirable to rely on external links, because once they are expired this question will be useless as a resource for people with similar problems who come here.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)